# What type is the best for loose numerically-indexed lists in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, types

What I need is something like an array but letting me to assign an element to whatever an index at any time and check if there is already a value assigned to particular index approximately like

```
MyArray<string> a = new MyArray<string>();
a[10] = "ten";
bool isTheFifthElementDefined = a[5] != null; // false
```

Perhaps `Dictionary<int, string>` with its `ContainsKey` method could do, but isn't there a more appropriate data structure if I want an ordered collection with numeric keys only?

I am also going to need to iterate through the defined elements (with foreach or linq preferably) accessing both the value and the key of current element.

Comment: You're not going to get anything out of the box for this, but I've created something similar in one of my projects called [`DynamicArray`](https://code.google.com/p/npeg/source/browse/PEG/Utils/DynamicArray.cs) which might be of some use to you.  Basically, it implements the metaphor you're looking for:  be able to assign a value at a particular index within an array regardless of whether the array is (currently) actually that large.

Comment: ArrayList may be used as well.

Comment: [SortedDictionary<int,string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)? What exactly do you want when you say "an ordered collection with numeric keys only"?

Comment: `Perhaps Dictionary<int, string> with its ContainsKey method could do, but isn't there a more appropriate data structure if I want an ordered collection with numeric keys only?` - No.

Comment: @Superbest: Well, actually, `Dictionary<int,string>` is not sorted, and enumerating the keys may return in any order.  Thus, `SortedDictionary<int,string>` is technically more appropriate.

Comment: Hey, @KirkWoll. I have chosen your DynamicArray<T> type to go (I will reference you when I release my project). Can you explain the `public DynamicArray<T> Copy()` function? I don't understand the  idea of `(List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(GetType());` Why not just use `new List<T>();` instead? I am getting problem using `.ToArray()` on this - I get `'System.InvalidCastException'` Unable to cast object of type 'MyProject.DynamicRefArray`1[MyProject.IMyInterface]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.IMyInterface]'.

Comment: @KirkWoll `DynamicRefArray` is the same as your `DynamicArray` but constrained to support reference types only: `public class DynamicRefArray<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class`

Comment: @Ivan, how embarassing, clearly that method was unexercised! :)  However, I believe I've fixed it, but I don't have the project in front of me so I can't test it.  But the whole method should just look like:  `DynamicArray<T> copy = new DynamicArray<T>(defaultValue);
copy.storage.AddRange(this); return copy;`.  Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: @KirkWoll It says `cannot access private field 'storage' here`.

Comment: @Ivan, I'm able to compile the code.  Is it possible you have both `DynamicArray` **and** `DynamicRefArray`?  If so, you'll need to make sure you reference whichever version actually contains the `Copy` method.

Comment: Ok @KirkWoll, just a moment, I will try to debug the thing...

Comment: Indeed, @KirkWoll, Your original code (just copied from the repository) does compile, so the problem seems to be in things I have added (and that's NOT about the `where T : class` constraint, adding it does not break your code). Have you also checked it to work as expected, not just to compile?

Comment: @Ivan, I'm happy to help further, but perhaps over email?  If you go to my project's code.google.com page, you should see my name on the left under Members.  If you jump through a hoop (by clicking on it) it will let you see my email and we can conduct this conversation that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned `Dictionary` seems more appropriate for this.But you can do it with generic lists,for example, when you are creating your list you can specify an element count,and you can give a default temporary value for all your elements.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(Enumerable.Repeat("",5000));
myList[2300] = "bla bla bla..";
```

For `int:`

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0,5000));
```

For `custom type`:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>(Enumerable.Repeat(new MyClass(), 100));
```

Ofcourse It is not the best solution...

Note: Also you can use [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Dictionary` if you want an ordered collection by keys:

> **`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`** : Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by key based on the associated IComparer implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need key/value pairs you cannot use a list, you'll need a Dictionary.
The implementation is pretty snappy so don't be too afraid about performance (as long as you don't put too much values in it).

You can iterate over it with

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in dict)
{
}
```

If you need to order it you can use a list:

```
List<int> ordered = new List(dict.Keys);
ordered.Sort();

foreach(int key in ordered)
{
}
```